# Mongoose pushing many documents into a document field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to push many documents into a field to populate my  mongo `db`, but for I keep getting the following error: `SyntaxError: Invalid property id`

This is the query I'm trying to do,

```js
db.stripeproducts.findOneAndUpdate(
{ stripeProductId: 'prod_Ijq9Y1uiFV0bSl' },
{$push: {
    bundlePhotoCodes: 
{value: 'XFTYUONMBUNDLE', status: 'valid', validUntil: null, modelID: null },
{value: 'XFTYUONMBUNDLE', status: 'valid', validUntil: null, modelID: null },
{value: 'YIHH878BUNDLE', status: 'valid', validUntil: null, modelID: null},
{value: 'HSGYGVI8BUNDLE', status: 'valid', validUntil: null, modelID: null},
{value: 'HSGYGVI8BUNDLE', status: 'valid', validUntil: null, modelID: null},
{value: 'BMDUKKSBUNDLE', status: 'valid', validUntil: null, modelID: null},
{value: 'XFTYUONMBUNGTY', status: 'valid', validUntil: null, modelID: null },
{value: 'YIHH878BUNTRD', status: 'valid', validUntil: null, modelID: null},
{value: '88UJHDI8BUNRSD', status: 'valid', validUntil: null, modelID: null}
{value: 'HSGYGVI8BUNQSD', status: 'valid', validUntil: null, modelID: null},
{value: 'HSGYGVI8BUNDDF', status: 'valid', validUntil: null, modelID: null},
{value: 'BMDUKKSBUNDFFF', status: 'valid', validUntil: null, modelID: null}
}},
{upsert: true}
)
```

This is my schema:

```js
const stripeProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    productName: String,
    productPrice: Number,
    productDescription: [{ type: String }],
    productImage: String,
    stripeProductId: String,
    stripePriceId: String,
    rate: String,
    amount: String,
    bundlePhotoCodes: [photoCodes],
    modelPayment: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'ModelPayment',
      required: false,
    },
  },
  { strict: true, timestamps: true },
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is invald. To append multiple values to an array, you need to use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push) with [$each](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/). For example:

```
db.stripeproducts.findOneAndUpdate(
  { stripeProductId: 'prod_Ijq9Y1uiFV0bSl' },
  {
    $push: {
      bundlePhotoCodes: {
        $each: [
          {value: 'XFTYUONMBUNDLE', status: 'valid', validUntil: null, modelID: null},
          {value: 'XFTYUONMBUNDLE', status: 'valid', validUntil: null, modelID: null},
          ...
       ]
     }
   }
 },
 {upsert: true}
)
```